# Wired USB mouse with freely spinning vertical wheel and a thumb wheel

Tags: usb, mice

I am looking for a mouse which can be used wired (so data transfer via USB cable is possible) which has the option of a freely spinning mouse wheel and a secondary, horizontal wheel (not buttons for horizontal scrolling).

So far I found the [Logitech MX master](https://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/mx-master)/ [Logitech MX master 2S](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/mx-master-2s-flow) office mice, but they seem to be only available with wireless data transfer. Otherwise they would be very nice, I had one of those under my hand in the shop.

I also fount the [madcatz R.A.T. 5 and madcatz R.A.T. 7 gaming mice](http://xahlee.info/kbd/madcatz_rat_gaming_mouse.html), but no information if they have free wheeling option for the vertical wheel. Do they?

Can anyone recommend a mouse with those specifications?

I want to use them for office, so gaming features are not needed (though not bad, either, if the mouse is good).